# Compare Matlab and Python variables

Tags: python, matlab

I am into a task where I am converting .m files to .py. But to test the code I have to dump or log values of each variables for both Python and Matlab in some log files.

Then I compare each after opening them in Excel sheet using its column property. Like what is the array index - what each index / column-row value is etc. This is very tiresome and I am not sure how we can compare variable / statements output for a specific variable programmatically in regards that it is just a .m to .py conversion.

Comment: Write a script that will compare the log files instead of doing this manually in Excel?

Comment: I tried that too but excel does that faster than script - I just copy formulas and paste it across. Is there a process which is more simplified or rather can be used for measuring outputs of both

Comment: `copy formulas ` - then you check Excel formulae. If I were to compare two programs I'd run two programs and compare their final outputs and intermediate results. Is this what you're doing? Also, a Python script is going to be way faster than Excel if written OK.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I am doing - I have to compare two programs outputs but also to test that the migration code is correct

Comment: `the migration code is correct` if you copied and changed it carefully and it gives the same output with the same input surely that means it's correct? What else do you want to check and how?

Comment: The issue is that I want to be sure that each values is what we get in MATLAB. Say a couple of values are incorrect that might not reflect in output cause comparably / visually it  would be difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the program in Matlab and save all the variables using the `save` command.  This saves to a `.mat` file.  Then you can load the variables from that file into python using `scipy.io.loadmat` and compare them in python.

First, in matlab:

```
save 'data.mat' var1 var2 var3
```

Then in python (in the same directory, or provide a full path):

```
import scipy.io
vars = scipy.io.loadmat('data.mat', squeeze_me=True)
var1_matlab = vars['var1']
var2_matlab = vars['var2']
var3_matlab = vars['var3']
```

Note that numpy has 1D arrays, while Matlab does not (1D arrays in Matlab are actually 2D arrays where one dimension has a length of 1).  This may mean that the number of dimensions in the python and scipy versions of a variable are different.  `squeeze_me` fixes this by eliminating dimensions with a length of 1, but it may, for example, take a 2D array from Matlab that happens to just have a length of 1 in some dimension and squeezes that to a 1D python array.  So you may have to do some manual dimension matching no matter what.

To get this to work, make sure matlab is configured to save files in the "MATLAB Version 5 or later" file format, though (in 2014B this is in `preferences`>`General`>`MAT-Files`).

If you absolutely must use version 7 files, you can try [hdf5storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage), which says it supports them.  However, you probably have scipy already installed, and I have personally used the scipy approach and confirmed it worked but have not done the same with hdf5storage.

Comment: Thanks I do have scipy and numpy packages installed. Thanks a lot for the information